# Are TeamCity parameterized VCS root considered same or different?

Tags: teamcity

I have TeamCity builds that linked to one VCS root. `Fetch URL` of the VCS root is parameterized. Every build is configured with its own git url. This works as expected: git only triggers build with the right url.

[image]

Then I have a deploy with snapshot dependencies on all previous builds:

[image]

[image]

All of the sudden, sometimes TC triggers undesired rebuilds, even if there are no changes in a repository. Builds are triggered by snapshot dependency.

I am investigating why rebuild happens, as it leads to overhead and produces too much docker images.

I found complex logic that depends on whether VCS roots same or not https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/dependent-build.html#Snapshot+Dependency.

Are links to VCS root with different `fetch URL` considered the same VCS root?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have made copies of the VCS root and actually it behaves the same as one VCS root with parameterized `Fetch URL`. E.g. my problem still remains: sometimes snapshot dependencies trigger all the builds even if there are no changes in the repository.